# Concise way of assigning a map entry only if new value is not empty or null in Groovy

Tags: groovy, gradle

I have this piece of code all over my gradle file:

```
def itemA = getVar('ITEM_A')
if (itemA) {
    envmap['itemA'] = itemA
}

def itemB = getVar('ITEM_B')
if (itemB) {
    envmap['itemB'] = itemB
}
```

Is there a much concise way of assigning to a variable only if new value is not null or empty?

Comment: Can't you just write a function to wrap that functionality?

Comment: Can I do something like this?:  setOnlyIfNonEmpty(envmap['itemB'], 'ITEM_B')

Comment: sure, something like `def envHelper = { map, vkey, mkey -> getVar(vkey).with { v -> envmap[mkey] = v } }` then call it with `envHelper(envmap, 'ITEM_A', 'itemA')`

Comment: Thanks, awesome.  I didn't know you could do that with maps.  Now, what if getVar() can potentially return a null?  Btw, mind creating an official answer?

Comment: good point...  corrected answer psted below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a helper closure like so:

```
def envHelper = { map, vkey, mkey ->
    getVar(vkey)?.with { v -> 
        envmap[mkey] = v
    }
}
```

then, you can replace

```
def itemA = getVar('ITEM_A')
if (itemA) {
    envmap['itemA'] = itemA
}
```

with

```
envHelper(envmap, 'ITEM_A', 'itemA')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use collectEntries and findAll to get a Map.

```
//An example of keys corresponding to your query
def keyNameFromVarName(String varName){
   varName.toLowerCase().replace('_','').substring(0,varName.length()-2)+
   varName.substring(varName.length()-1,varName.length())
}

def varNames = ['ITEM_C', 'ITEM_D', 'ITEM_E', 'ITEM_F', 'ITEM_G', 'ITEM_H']

Map map = varNames.collectEntries{ [ (keyNameFromVarName(it)) : getVar(it) ] }.findAll{ k,v-> v }
```

First use collectEntries on the list object. Remember to put the generation of the map key inside parentheses or you will get a compilation error.

```
varNames.collectEntries{ [ (keyNameFromVarName(it)) : getVar(it) ] }
```

Then use findAll to get the entries where the value is not null. Define k,v as parameters to the closure for easy access to the value.

```
.findAll{ k,v-> v }
```